# Error when trying to authorize Axios get request

Tags: rest, http, axios, postman

I am trying to access the Uber API with Axios and I am running into some trouble. I have plugged this data into Postman and I get a 200 response code with no problems. However, when I try to make an Axios call, I get response code 401 unauthorized. Can I get some help looking through my code to find out why my authorization is not working correctly with Axios?

Here is a link to the Uber API docs I am referencing. [Uber API Reference](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/estimates-price-get)

```
getRide_Uber = async (addressOrigin, addressDestination) => {
  let origin = await geocodeAddress(addressOrigin);
  let destination = await geocodeAddress(addressDestination);

  const url = "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/price";

  const params = {
    params: {
      start_latitude: origin.lat,
      start_longitude: origin.lon,
      end_latitude: destination.lat,
      end_longitude: destination.lon
    }
  };

  const headers = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Token ${process.env.UBER_SERVER_TOKEN}`
    }
  };

  const response = await axios
    .get(url, params, headers)
    .then(function(response) {
      data = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  return data;
};
```

Please let me know if anything needs clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below syntax,

```
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Token ${process.env.UBER_SERVER_TOKEN}`
    } 
    params: {
      start_latitude: origin.lat,
      start_longitude: origin.lon,
      end_latitude: destination.lat,
      end_longitude: destination.lon
    }
  };

  const response = await axios
    .get(url, config)
    .then(function(response) {
      data = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  return data;
```

There is one more aspect axios, async/await is not supported in Internet Explorer and older browsers. So also please check your browser versions as well.

Comment: This got it!!! Thank you so much @Mukund. I accepted this as the answer. Why does wrapping this in config fix my problem?

Comment: axios  'get' method takes url and config object and config object holds both header and params. So we need to wrapping them in single.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how are you getting token from env but seems the server token is not getting pass correctly, may be few extra characters while reading from env. Try to run the program first with hard coded token in program itself and once you are sure its not code issue, you can move it into config/env and then debug env read issue.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this! Before posting this I did have the key hard coded which makes me doubt that this is the issue. Is the formatting correct to your knowledge?